# How do click row table in modal bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, html-table

I have bound data in a table and show them in modal bootstrap. 
I want get data of row table using click or double click , but it's not working
[image]

```
   <div class="modal-body">
                <table id="table_search" class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CCA</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>  
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

And I use jquery as follows

```
 $('#table_search > tbody > tr').click(function () {
            alert( $(this).val());
        });

        $('#table_search > tbody > tr').dblclick(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Are you binding the click event before or after the modal is triggered?

Comment: Ok, Three answer is good.Thank men.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle. The others beat me to the core of the solution. I bascially have a combination of their answers in the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/stephen_hartzell/seapkzvv/

The HTML

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <table id="table_search" class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>CCA</td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>  
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>b</td>
                        <td>c</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

The Javascript

```
$('#table_search > tbody').on('click', '>tr', function () {
     alert( $(this).text());
});


$('#table_search > tbody > tr').dblclick(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that "click" is binding the element before it even exists. You'll have to rebind after the rows have been added to the DOM, or bind a parent structure to any child selector with "on":

```
 $('#table_search > tbody').on('click', '>tr', function () {
        alert( $(this));
    });

    $('#table_search > tbody').on('dblclick', '>tr', function () {
        alert($(this));
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be using an event delegate here or attaching the events
when the modal is shown. Also `tr` doesn't have a value you want the text

```
$(document).on('click dblclick', '#table_search > tbody > tr', function (e) {
   alert($(this).text());
});
```